# Does AsciiDoc support layers or text on images?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm making a poster (sort of) and would like to do these things, but I'm not sure if AsciiDoc or AsciiDoctor can do them, and if so, how:

- Background image that can be stretched to the poster's dimensions
- A rectangle with some transparency and a border, basically a bright frame, with text in it.
- An image with text in it.
- Text inside an image inside a rectangle.

(Bonus question: Is it possible to free-form specify where something goes, e.g. x=80%, y = 20% for something in the top right corner?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it makes sense to use AsciiDoc to source poster output, as opposed to a desktop publishing tool or a graphics program.

But if you are converting to HTML, you should be able to accomplish most of this with clever sourcing and some CSS/JavaScript on the front end. That is, you can source some of the metadata you want to impose on the final image, then have front-end code do the manipulation and imposition. For instance, you can provide a caption, classes, a title, and other info in the source, but AsciiDoc is intentionally agnostic about how that stuff is handled in output.

However, unless you need to create these things as part of technical documents, especially ones getting built/generated recuringly with automation, you're likely better off with a specialized tool.